# Manage files across external SSDs

Tags: file-management, file-search

I want to be able to find which SSD contains a particular file without manually plugging in and trying each drive.

I'm considering to index each SSD as a text file, which can be `grep`'d to find the SSD in question:

```
# index like this
cd /media/storage/ssd_name
find > ~/Desktop/SSDs/ssd_name

# search like this
cd ~/Desktop/SSDs
grep "file name"
```

This feels like reinventing the wheel. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**[NeoFinder](https://www.cdfinder.de)**

> The Holy Grail of Media Asset Management (according to ZDNet)
> NeoFinder (was CDFinder) quickly catalogs and manages your entire media and disk library, and your backup archive.

Very mature cataloguing solution. I've been using it since it was 'CDFinder', back in the 90s.
Search a file, it tells you which disk it's on. Once you feed the disk to the OS, it can then action it.
Cataloguing is automatic [every time it sees that drive again] or manual.